# select different column from different rows

Tags: sqlite

I've searched and tried a lot, but could not get any answer to it. I need a sqlite query for a table like

```
ID     Name     Address     Phone
1               yyyy        zzz
1      aaa      bbbb        ccc
```

The query should return the result like

```
1      aaa      yyyy        zzz
```

So name from second non empty record and address and phone from first record (first record can be empty also or it may not event exist).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the records ordered? (They have the same ID.)

Comment: Rows in a table have no order (technically they have but this order is arbitrary and may even change over time). You have to care about ordering yourself by providing criteria for sorting rows.

Comment: Yes, you can consider same ID. I want the query with clause `...where ID=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made the query myself. Suppose below is test table

```
ID     Name     Address     Phone
1               yyyy        zzz
1      aaa      bbbb        ccc
2      rrrr
```

so the query below

```
SELECT b.name,a.address, a.phone from test a  
    join (select id,name,address from test where id=1 ) b on a.id = b.id 
    where b.name is not null and (a.address is null or a.address!=b.address)
```

will give `'aaa','yyyy','zzz'`

and

```
SELECT b.name,a.address, a.phone from test a  
    join (select id,name,address from test where id=2 ) b on a.id = b.id 
    where b.name is not null and (a.address is null or a.address!=b.address)
```

will give `'rrrr',,`